# Is the series uniform convergent in $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

For  $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$$
And is it bounded in $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}=\frac\pi x\coth\frac\pi x$

Comment: @Lucian how lead to this conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

not uniformly convergent, since by picking $x = 1/n^2$ you can get the $n$-th term to be $1/2$ and since $n$ was arbitrary and your series has positive terms this contradicts uniform convergence. it's also not bounded since the terms are decreasing for a fixed $x$. what we've done before shows that you can get a sum bigger than $n/2$ for any $n$.

Comment: why $\frac{n}{2}$??

Comment: we've shown that the $n$-th term is equal to $1/2$ with this choice of $x$. therefore all the first $n$ terms are $\geq 1/2$ and hence the result (we neglect all the terms apart from the first $n$)

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sup_{x}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+k^2x}\geq\sup_{x}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{1+k^2x}\geq \sup_{x}\frac{n}{1+4n^2x}=n$$

which does not converge to $0$.  So the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding the second $\ge$..

Comment: There are $n$ terms each larger than the last term.

Comment: and why does it equal to $n$?

Comment: As $x$ goes to $0$ it increases to $n$, becoming arbitrarily close. Hence the sup is n and the sequence of partial sums does not uniformly satisfy the Cauchy criterion for $x >0$.